# css button set to unclickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to set the CSS on a button to unclickable/disable. I have a form, when I click on the "send" button, then I want to set the button to disable/unclickable. How do I do this?

Here is the button:

```
.good-form > .actions a,
.theButton {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 540px;
    margin: 20px 0 10px;
    padding: 12px;
    background-color: #b6adb4;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;

}
```

and here is the jquery:

Firstly, I tried this: NOT WORKING!

```
$(".good-form > .actions a, .theButton").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Secondy, I tried this: NOT WORKING

```
$(".good-form > .actions a, .theButton").addClass('disabled');
```

or

```
$(".good-form > .actions a, .theButton").addClass("disabled");
```

Comment: Can you add your **HTML** code please !

Comment: You can set `pointer-events: none;` on the button

Comment: is your class added successfully when you used second code?

Comment: It is not a form element, it is just an anchor. Disabled attribute will not work.

Comment: It looks like the issue is with your selector - without the html, it's impossible to tell exactly what the issue is.

Comment: Your "button" is just a shape you drew with CSS?   In your click handler you'll need to check and set a "been here" variable.

Comment: But using pointer-events will not help in automation testing of the button. The button can still be clickable using scripts.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I hope this is working (`disabled` class added successfully):-

```
$(".good-form > .actions a, .theButton").addClass('disabled');
// IF NOT THEN USE $(".theButton").addClass('disabled');
```

Now add CSS like below:-

```
.disabled{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

***This will also work*** (without additional CSS) :-

```
$(".good-form > .actions a, .theButton").prop('disabled',true); 
// or $(".theButton").prop('disabled',true);
```

Comment: But using pointer-events will not help in automation testing of the button. The button can still be clickable using scripts.

Answer (score 21):

Try adding a class in your element and provide below css to it :-

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="Save" class="Disabled"/>
```

**CS**

```
.Disabled{
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  opacity: 0.65;
  filter: alpha(opacity=65);
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
```

}

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 3):

The code you are looking for is (assuming the button has an ID).

```
document.getElementById("theButton").disabled = true;
```

And you can style it in css like so:

```
#theButton:disabled{
   background: white;
   /*or whatever*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this is pure JS, HTML and CSS (i hope i helped)

```js
/* ignore top lines */
document.getElementById("theButton").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
/* ignore top lines */

function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("theButton").disabled = true;
}
```

```css
.theButton {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 540px;
    margin: 20px 0 10px;
    padding: 12px;
    background-color: #b6adb4;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.theButton:disabled {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 540px;
    margin: 20px 0 10px;
    padding: 12px;
    background-color: #b6adb4;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<button class="theButton" id="theButton">
Click to disable
</button>
```

JSFIDDLE HERE: https://jsfiddle.net/HappyFone/swhbjer8/8/

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
$(".good-form > .actions a, .theButton").prop('disabled',true);
```

Comment: Just FYI, it's `prop()`, not `props()`, and the second parameter should be a boolean

Answer (score 1):

To disable button

```
$(".good-form > .actions a, .theButton").prop('disabled', true);
```

Css for disabled button

```
.theButton:disabled { /* YOUR CSS */}
```

Comment: There is no literal  `TRUE` in js. It should be boolean `true` (smallcaps).

Comment: Actually not (smallcaps), small letters.